# Build:Cannot find type definition file for webpack-env why this error occur while building the solution

Tags: build, tsc, build-error

while building the solution "Build:Cannot find type definition file for webpack-env" this error is occured it metion that it is in tsc file but i can't find such a file due to this error i am not able to build this solution

I am building the solution for runing unit test in test explorer. I want to run test methods for that need to solve the above build error